# Not able to understand terraform cyclic dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Can someone please help me to understand the cyclic dependency in this terraform graph.

[image]

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution myself.

Actually I have set **create_before_destroy** life cycle parameter to **true** only in instance and not to an dependent user_data.

After setting that property in **template_file** user_data as well the problem got resolved.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me.